# qsort() works in one direction, but not other

Tags: c, arrays, char, quicksort

This is how I made my comparison function to pass to qsort():

```
int charCompare(const void* ptr1, const void* ptr2)
{
   char c1 = *(char*)ptr1;
   char c2 = *(char*)ptr2;
   return c1 - c2;
}
```

And this is the implementation:

```
char buffer[SIZE];
/*
 * buffer filled here
 */
qsort(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(char), sizeof(char), charCompare);
printf("%s", buffer);
```

Nothing gets printed. I'm pretty sure it's because the null characters are coming before the regular characters, since it works the other way (if I return c2-c1 instead from charCompare). But how would I go about getting rid of the null characters, since I want it to be in order from a to z, not the other way around?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is **always** 1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are exactly right that the null(s) are getting included.  You are sorting the entire buffer, not just the part that contains your (null terminated) string.  You need to use `strlen(buffer)` rather than `sizeof(buffer)` (and include `string.h` of course).  You also don't need to divide by `sizeof(char)` since the `sizeof` function is defined in terms of `char`-sized units.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a buffer that contains '\0' characters and you want them to not end up at the start of the buffer, just make sure `'\0'` sorts to the end of the array:

```
int charCompare(const void* ptr1, const void* ptr2)
{
   int c1 = *(char*)ptr1;
   int c2 = *(char*)ptr2;

   if (c1 == 0) c1 = INT_MAX;
   if (c2 == 0) c2 = INT_MAX;

   return c1 - c2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your initial buffer starts off filled with an ordinary C string, which has only a single null terminator at the end, and you want it to end up that way, then you can just exclude the last spot from the sort:

```
qsort(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, charCompare);
```